# Android Studio/IntelliJ - Where do I manage the JRE list for unit tests?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I must be missing something terribly obvious here: Since some recent Android Studio update/reinstall (I can't remember) I have to manually set the JRE that should be used - otherwise, an invalid path will be used and the test will fail.

Where do I manage this list? I would like to remove all invalid entries and duplicates.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently Intellij Idea does not provide a way to remove the list of JRE Entries. You can try the followings.

1. First uninstall Intellij Idea editor.
2. Go to the directory C:\Users\ if you are using windows, remove the folder/s like .IdeaIC. or .IdeaIU.
3. Reinstall Intellij Idea and select the appropriate JDK version.

OR You can do the following.

1. As per the above screen shot point to you JDK location.

It will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the `.IdeacIC` - or in my case `.AndroidStudio3.4` - folder! There's the file `.AndroidStudio3.4/config/options/jdk.table.xml` which contains the actual list and can be edited to remove duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

After following @Sambit's hints and looking around some more I found the solution: The list is stored in (in my case) `~/.AndroidStudio3.4/config/options/jdk.table.xml`. There, each list item is represented by a `<jdk>` element. After removing all the unwanted entries and restarting Android Studio (complete restart, not just close/open project) I now have list that looks much nicer:

[image]

I have not tried what happens when you mess up the XML structure so take care!